# How can I prevent entrybox to get focus when switching to a new ttk notebook tab python?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

[CODE]

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

root = Tk()
noteBook = Notebook(root)
root.focus()
tab1 = Frame(noteBook)
tab2 = Frame(noteBook)
Label(tab2, text='Test', width=15).grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W)
Entry(tab2, width=40).grid(row=3,column=1)
noteBook.add(tab1, text = "tab 1", compound=TOP)
noteBook.add(tab2, text = "tab 2")
noteBook.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[CURRENT OUTPUT] the entryBox is focused when I click on tab2.

[DESIRED OUTPUT] the entryBox should not be focused.

[NOTE] if I double click on tab2, then it gets the focus. even if comment out the line 'root.focus()', the entryBox still has focus.

Comment: why do you want that? What is wrong with giving the entry widget focus? What widget should have focus instead? A GUI always has to have something with the keyboard focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `takeFocus` to `False` on your `Entry`.

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

root = Tk()
noteBook = Notebook(root)
root.focus()
tab1 = Frame(noteBook)
tab2 = Frame(noteBook)
Label(tab2, text='Test', width=15).grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W)
Entry(tab2, width=40, takefocus=False).grid(row=3,column=1)
noteBook.add(tab1, text = "tab 1", compound=TOP)
noteBook.add(tab2, text = "tab 2")
noteBook.pack()
root.mainloop()
```